# Unable to Debug Code

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a very weird issue with Access. I have a form for which I created a command button with a simple sub for the Click event:

```
MsgBox "Hello"
```

When I put a break point in, it doesn't stop at the break statement, it just executes the sub. I don't program in access everyday but I have been coding on/off with Access for over 10 years. I have never had this issue, and I have worked on this clients Access Database before.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you compacted and repaired and decompiled http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/decompile.htm?

Comment: what happens if you place a `Stop` command in the line before the `MsgBox`?

Comment: Remou: This link Says it's for Access 97 , Peter: If i put a stop before nothing happens as well. If i put a syntax error and run it, it stops running shows me the line with the syntax error but not in debug mode!

Comment: I've had this issue before and it was related to not having enough memory - a reboot cleared it.

Comment: It is by Tony Toews, MS Access MVP and an acknowledge expert on corruption, last update 2010/10/23. Scroll down to decompile and follow the instructions after you have compacted and repaired.

Comment: Remou, Unfortunately I won't be able to do that right now. I don't have much rights on the PC i am remotely connected to. I will ask for the access and Let you know what happens.

Comment: Do you have Access Options->Current Database->Use Access Special Keys checked?  If it is not, breakpoints won't be triggered.

Comment: Well Zaider, Thanks! That worked please Answer the question and I will mark it as correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you check `Access Options->Current Database->Use Access Special Keys` option, break points will no longer be triggered.  Having this option unchecked also prevents things such as F11 opening the access objects window.